# Sincronizar projeto no visual studio com o team service

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server, cloud

Boa noite.

Como faço para as modificações feitas pela minha equipe sejam vistas no meu pc? Sou iniciante na tecnologia do team service do visual studio.

Ex: Um integrante da minha equipe criou um form e fez o Check in no projeto, no site eu vejo o que ele modificou. Mas quando abro o meu visual studio na aba de "Team Service" e seleciono o projeto, ele não sincroniza o que esta na nuvem, ficando apenas os arquivos que estão na minha maquina.

Comment: Consegui, o integrante do meu grupo deveria fazer check in do projeto todo e não apenas da form. clico com o botão esquedo em cima do "Solution" no visual studio e peço para baixar a ultima versão do projeto, assim ele sincroniza.

Comment: Uma ferramenta interessante caso você não saiba é que se você clicar com o botão direito na solution>source control>view history, você verá todos os check-ins feitos,  e clicando no check-in>changeset details, você consegue ver quais forms,classes,html's etc ele modificou...